# sql server developer throttled?

Tags: sql-server

I know SQL Server Developer is functionally equivalent to SQL Server Enterprise.  But surely it's less performant in some way (can't leverage as much memory, only works against one core, etc)?

Is SQL Server Developer edition throttled in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Developer Edition is exactly the same in all respects, performance-wise.

Only the licencing differs.